# program different key to select proposal from content assist

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard, jface, content-assist

I am trying to implement content assist for a textViewer from the JFace library on my stand-alone java application. It has been working thus far. However, I was wondering if it is possible to change the key used to select the proposal from the popup? I want to use the ENTER key for something else in my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The proposals list is shown by `org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup` and there does not seem to be a way to change what it does or to use a different class.